# Export Pandas DataFrame with Applied Syles to pdf or png

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is there a way to export a DataFrame with applied styles from a Jupyter notebook to an image file, with the styles applied?

Comment: Can't u use the screenshot tools provided in Windows, Mac, Linux.. ? Or are you looking for something more automated?

Comment: Looking for something automated.

Comment: Ok, I'd start with providing a small example with your styled format. Possibly some html output that you can convert to PDF. Have you checked this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678467/export-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-table-image

Comment: [Does this question help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38095436/4650297)?