# Exporting pandas table as pdf

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I found quite a nice way to export a table generated with `pandas` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678467/export-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-table-image) to PDF, the part about converting it to a png file is uninteresting to me.

The problem is, that I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9818a71c26bb> in <module>()
     13 
     14 with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
---> 15     f.write(template.format(z.to_latex()))
     16 
     17 subprocess.call(['pdflatex', filename])

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm not really understanding the code in the first place which makes it quite hard to correct the error. My code looks like this:

```
import subprocess

filename = 'out.tex'
pdffile = 'out.pdf'

template = r'''\documentclass[preview]{{standalone}}
\usepackage{{booktabs}}
\begin{{document}}
{}
\end{{document}}
'''

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(template.format(z.to_latex()))

subprocess.call(['pdflatex', filename])
```

where `z` is a `DataFrame` generated with `pandas`.

Hope someone can help out.
Thank you in advance,
Sito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're opening a file to write in bytes mode - that's what the "b" character means in the call to `open()` - and then passing it string data. Change this:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(template.format(z.to_latex()))
```

to this:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(template.format(z.to_latex()))
```