# Converting TeX file to image in Python

Tags: python, pandas, latex, pdflatex

Using [this accepted answer as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678467/export-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-table-image), I've been trying to replicate the pandas DF *to* TeX *to* PDF *to* png recipe. However, my Python 3 (using a Jupyter Notebook thru Anaconda Navigator) is giving me some trouble.

I've installed MiKTeX at the following default location on my local disk:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\2.9
```

I also installed LaTex at the following location:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\extensions\TeX
```

However, when I run the chunk of code using my Pandas df object:

```
filename = 'out.tex'
pdffile = 'out.pdf'
outname = 'out.png'

template = r'''\documentclass[preview]{{standalone}}
\usepackage{{booktabs}}
\begin{{document}}
{}
\end{{document}}
'''

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(template.format(df.to_latex()),'UTF-8'))


subprocess.call(['pdflatex', filename], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['convert', '-density', '300', pdffile, '-quality', '90', outname])
```

It's simply returning "4", and the only file created from my original df is "**out.tex**". I'd like the DF to be turned into a png image so I can keep the full process in my Notebook script.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using the following two process calls:

```
subprocess.call('latex -interaction=batchmode -output-directory='+ outpath + ' ' + input_tex_file, shell=True, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'))
subprocess.call('dvipng -q* -T tight -o ' + output_png_file + ' ' + input_dvi_file, shell=True, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'))
```

You'll have to create `.tex` file first from your raw latex data. Then these commands first create a `.dvi` file (and some additional auxiliary files) from the `.tex` file. You can then use dvipng (https://ctan.org/pkg/dvipng?lang=en) to create a `.png` file.