# How to change the whole row text color after a specific condition on matplotlib table?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a code which converts a pandas dataframe to table [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678467/export-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-table-image)
Now, I want to change the whole row color based on specific condition. If one of the cell meets my condition then the text color of whole row will be changed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import six

trend = ['uptrend', 'downtrend', '10 uptrend', '20 downtrend']
value = ['10', '20', '30', '50']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Trend':trend, 'Value':value})


def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                 header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                 bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                 ax=None, **kwargs):
   if ax is None:
     size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
     print(size)
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
     ax.axis('off')

  mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

  mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
  mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

  for k, cell in  six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
      cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
      if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
          cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
          cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
      else:
          cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])

      if 'uptrend' in cell.get_text().get_text():
          cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='g')
      elif 'downtrend' in cell.get_text().get_text():
          cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='r')
  return ax


render_mpl_table(
    df, 
    header_columns=0, 
    header_color='#40466e', 
    edge_color='grey', 
    row_height = 1, 
    col_width=2.5
)
```

[I want to change all cell's text colors if one condition is met. Like I want to change the color of 10 to green, 20 red, 30 green and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKcrB.png)

Comment: As the coordinates of the table can be specified in tuples, the following code can be added to the if condition to make 10 green. `if 'uptrend' in cell.get_text().get_text():cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='g');mpl_table._cells[(k[0],k[1]+1)].set_text_props(weight='bold', color='g')`

Comment: @r-beginners mpl_table._cells[(k[0],k[1]+1)].set_text_props(weight='bold', color='g') this chunk of code only change the color if my column number is two. I have added another column but the color of that column doesn't change.

Comment: `print(k)` will print the coordinates of the table in tuple form: (k[0].k[1]+2) when the third column is added.

Comment: any way to add the last coordinate dynamically? Like if the data frame changes every time it will automatically take the length of the row.

Comment: The number of rows in the target DF can be obtained with `len(df)`and`len(mpl._table._cells)`, and the number of columns with `len(df.columns)` .